# Using datetime to determine highest frequency event within a time interval

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, iteration

I have a dataframe that includes a number of statistics on crime, including the date and time of the crime as well as the category.

```
0       5/13/2015 8:55           VEHICLE THEFT   
1       5/13/2015 8:41          OTHER OFFENSES   
2       5/13/2015 8:36          OTHER OFFENSES   
3       5/13/2015 8:30            NON-CRIMINAL   
4       5/13/2015 8:17          OTHER OFFENSES   
5       5/13/2015 8:16          OTHER OFFENSES   
6       5/13/2015 8:10           LARCENY/THEFT   
7       5/13/2015 8:00                BURGLARY   
8       5/13/2015 8:00          MISSING PERSON   
9       5/13/2015 8:00          OTHER OFFENSES   
10      5/13/2015 8:00                 ASSAULT 
---
```

So for the above sample, it would simply print: "Other Offenses."

It is a massive database, over 400,000 rows.

I need to write a function that will allow me to enter any given time range (using from and to) and then determine which crime category occurred with the most frequency.  This is what I have, and it is not working:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime
timeData = open("timeData.csv")
df = pd.read_csv('timeData.csv')

from datetime import timedelta, date
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']) #this converts the values in the Dates column to datetime format

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2015, 5, 1)
end_date = date(2015, 6, 2)
for daterange(start_date, end_date):
    df['Category'].value_counts()
```

I want to iterate through the Dates column (Column A) and select only those dates that fit within my daterange.  For the dates within my daterange, I then want to count the number of instances of each crime (Column B).  Having done this, I want to print the Crime that occurs most frequently.

Suggestions?

Comment: it looks to me like you are trying to reinvent the [date_range()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) function ;-)

Comment: Being a noob, I probably am....How would that work for my purposes?

Comment: can you post a desired data set for the posted input data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to make this efficient-er, set your index to be the dates.  Assume your dates column is `Date` and crime categories are `Crime`

```
# make pd.Series with date as the index and crimes as the values
d1 = df.set_index('Date').Crime.sort_index()

# function that uses date slicing and uses values counts
def most_freq(start, end):
    return d1[start:end].value_counts().index[0]

# demo
most_freq('2015-05', '2015-05')

'OTHER_OFFENSES'
```

Comment: I deleted my comment because I did not realize `value_counts()` sorts by value. Sorry!

Comment: @piRSquared Ok--I created your modified DataFrame "d1" as above.  That worked.  But when I used your code to define the most_freq function, I got a SyntaxError here:  --->def most_freq('2003-05', '2015-04'):  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I defined the function `most_freq` specifying the input variables `start` and `end`.  When you use it, don't use the `def`!  Just call the function `most_freq('2003-05', '2015-04')`

Comment: Oh...duh.  Thanks!  Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to group your DF by date:

```
In [204]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])['crime'].value_counts()
Out[204]:
date        crime
2015-05-13  OTHER OFFENSES    5
            ASSAULT           1
            BURGLARY          1
            LARCENY/THEFT     1
            MISSING PERSON    1
            NON-CRIMINAL      1
            VEHICLE THEFT     1
Name: crime, dtype: int64
```

or:

```
In [201]: df
Out[201]:
                  date           crime
0  2015-05-13 08:55:00   VEHICLE THEFT
1  2015-05-13 08:41:00  OTHER OFFENSES
2  2015-05-13 08:36:00  OTHER OFFENSES
3  2015-05-13 08:30:00    NON-CRIMINAL
4  2015-05-13 08:17:00  OTHER OFFENSES
5  2015-05-13 08:16:00  OTHER OFFENSES
6  2015-05-13 08:10:00   LARCENY/THEFT
7  2015-05-13 08:00:00        BURGLARY
8  2015-05-13 08:00:00  MISSING PERSON
9  2015-05-13 08:00:00  OTHER OFFENSES
10 2015-05-13 08:00:00         ASSAULT

In [202]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'), 'crime']).size()
Out[202]:
date        crime
2015-05-13  ASSAULT           1
            BURGLARY          1
            LARCENY/THEFT     1
            MISSING PERSON    1
            NON-CRIMINAL      1
            OTHER OFFENSES    5
            VEHICLE THEFT     1
dtype: int64
```